# mysql database timing out during backup?

Tags: mysql, backup

I am having a problem backing up a database. I’m moving between vps providers and usually would use the WHM transfer tool. I did it this time also but got database error messages after the transfer and when I compared the 2 databases I noticed that the newer one was 200Mb smaller than the old one n the old server so I have been trying to take a manual backup but I’m having the same problem..

The original database is 1.1Gb. I’ve tried dumping it via command line, exporting from phpmyadmin, cpanel backups etc but each time I`m left with a smaller database.

I have checked both old and new databases, all the tables are backing up fine but its the contents of them which are not fully backing up. which makes me think it may be a timeout issue, .. But I am not 100% sure. I have tried changing settings in php.ini and my.cnf but I am not totally sure what is causing the prob.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The physical database size may be different because the new database hasn't had inserts and updates. Do the tables have different amounts of data?

Comment: The `mysqldump` tool is pretty junk for dealing with large databases. At that point you might want to try [InnoBackupEx](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_script.html) which works much, much better.